# Is $u_n$ where $\left\{\begin{matrix}u_{1}=5 \\ u_{n}=\frac{2^{u_{n-1}}+1}{3} \end{matrix}\right.$ always prime?

Tags: prime-numbers

$\left\{\begin{matrix}u_{1}=5 \\ u_{n}=\frac{2^{u_{n-1}}+1}{3}  \end{matrix}\right.$

I conjecture that $u_{n}$ is prime number. But I can not prove it. So I want to know my conjecture is right or wrong.

Comment: Why do you think this works?

Comment: Reminds me of a famous [conjecture by Fermat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Primality_of_Fermat_numbers), disproved by Euler...

Answer (score 7):

No. WolframAlpha says that $u_4$ is not prime and is equal to $$1676083\times \\26955961001\times\\
29608434354586376051669975373338765263536609888911641073166192\\
42535637290590853367799328108998193136129252550026666912268005\\
07277398580985624625950496168983999760414855301693388419156899841$$

Comment: What did you put as the query in WA?

Comment: I put "Is (2^683+1)/3 prime?" (where I determined earlier that $u_1=5, u_2=11, u_3=683$ are prime).

Comment: It's amazing to me that Mathematica can handle such large numbers. CASs are pretty sweet.